# Adding watermark in video

Tags: javascript, java

Is it possible to watermark a video with the phone number which was entered at the registration time by the subscriber in an OTT-like web platform?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a WebServer and your page isn't static you can create an image with the phone number and overlay this image with FFmpeg.

You could also display the phone number on top of youre video but It won't be integrated if the user can download it: https://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/

https://github.com/dotsub/videojs-watermark